# Generalizing the proof of simplicity of the alternating groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

The standard proof for the simplicity of the alternating groups consists of three claims.  If $n \ge 5$ then
(1) all elements of $A_n$ are products of 3-cycles,
(2) all 3-cycles in $A_n$ are conjugate,
and
(3) any nontrivial normal subgroup must contain a 3-cycle.
Thus any nontrivial normal subgroup of $A_n$ is equal to $A_n$.

$Question.$ Are there other families of simple groups that would fit a similar argument, replacing "is a 3-cycle" with some property $P$?

In preparation for teaching a group theory class this spring, I'm curious if there is $another$ family (projective special linear groups, for example?) where one could create a proof of simplicity by finding a property $P$ such that (1) the groups in the family are generated by elements with property $P$; (2) elements of property $P$ are conjugate and (3) nontrivial normal subgroups must contain an element of property $P$.

Comment: How about the "simple-simple" groups (as my graduate algebra professor called them), the cyclic groups of prime order?  There aren't that many infinite families of simple groups to choose from.

Comment: If you plan to unify the treatment of the alternating groups with the PSLs, my only hope would be to adapt Iwasawa's simplicity criterion to the alternating groups (making things for them slightly more complicated), and let the 3-cycles play the role of the transvections.

Comment: Yes, reading a bit ... the transvections for the PSLs looks like the same type of thing... thanks!